# How to pass several patterns into HTML input by markup only (no JS)

Tags: html, regex

Following input is accepting a phone input like `555-555-5555` because of `pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"`.

Can I combine the pattern with other condition like also accepting format like `5555555555`?

```
<input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone"
   pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" pattern="^\d{10}$"
 required>
```

Comment: You can either modify the pattern you have as shown below, or modify it with `|` operator to add any more variations, but you cannot pass two same `pattern` attributes with different regexps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a single pattern with an optional capture group to capture `-` and a backreference `\1` to that group to pair up the hyphen to not match `555-5555555`

For the [pattern attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern#constraint_validation) you can omit the anchors `^` and `$` as they are implicit.

```
[0-9]{3}(-)?[0-9]{3}\1[0-9]{4}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6EipOt/1)